# Combine 2 same size lists to one list of dicts Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have two same size lists:

```
['/phoenix', '/scottsdale', '/tempe']
['Phoenix', 'Scottsdale', 'Tempe']
```

How can I combine them to one list of dicts:

```
[
    {'slug': '/phoenix', 'title': 'Phoenix'},
    {'slug': '/scottsdale', 'title': 'Scottsdale'},
    {'slug': '/tempe', 'title': 'Tempe'}
]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
l1 = ['/phoenix', '/scottsdale', '/tempe']
l2 = ['Phoenix', 'Scottsdale', 'Tempe']
print([{'slug': a, 'title': b} for (a, b) in zip(l1, l2)])
```

---

Output:

```
[{'slug': '/phoenix', 'title': 'Phoenix'},
 {'slug': '/scottsdale', 'title': 'Scottsdale'},
 {'slug': '/tempe', 'title': 'Tempe'}]
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I wanted!